# check leap year or not in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

How to check the given year is leap year or not in PostgreSQL.?

I tried below query.But it is showing error message.

```
select extract(year from hiredate)% 4 = 0 from emp
```

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: Cast the result of `extract()` to `integer`:  `select extract(year from hiredate) % 4 = 0 from emp;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must cast the extracted year to an integer.

```
select extract(year from hiredate)::integer % 4 = 0 from emp
```

However, that is the incorrect formula for a leap year. It is Every four years except every 100 except every 400. 1900 was not a leap year, but 2000 was.

```
create function is_leap_year(timestamp)
returns boolean as $$
declare y integer;
begin
  y := extract(year from $1);
  return (y % 4 = 0) and (y % 100 <> 0 or y % 400 = 0);
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

---

Alternatively, you can check to see what day comes before March 1st in that year. This is safer as it will use Postgresql's internal logic.

```
create function is_leap_year(timestamp)
returns boolean as $$
begin
  return date_part(
    'day',
    make_date(date_part('year', $1)::int, 3, 1) - '1 day'::interval
  ) = 29;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```